# ObservableBoolean.get() always give null pointer exception

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-databinding

My ObservableBoolean always trigger null pointer exception "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.databinding.ObservableBoolean.get()' on a null object reference"

I'm trying to call it through the binded view. The view model looks like this:

```
class TempViewModel {
    val isLayoutVisible: ObservableBoolean = ObservableBoolean(false)

    fun onClicked(view: View){
        isLayoutVisible.set(!isLayoutVisible.get())
    }
}
```

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>

    <variable
            name="tempViewModel"
            type="com.example.project.TempViewModel"/>
</data>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{tempViewModel::onClicked}"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_exclamation"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="@{tempViewModel.isLayoutVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

The click listeners goes into onClicked but then it crashes on isLayoutVisible.get(). Anyone know why?